# Scaling images in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have to display a bunch of images in a page. Images are of different size, some very wide and some very thin. I want to put them all in a container of fixed width and fixed height.

Say if image is smaller, we retain the size and put it at the center of container. if image is bigger, we scale it down according to the prominent direction.

Our container is 500x500 and image is say 1000x400, then it will be scaled like 500x200. Similarly if image is 400x1000, then scaled image is 200x500. Is this doable with just html/css. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm much mistaken, mostly due to never having actually done this, but don't the width and height propeties of the img tag take care of this?

Comment: @WebDevHobo width and height do scale the image but it doesn't perserve aspect ratio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max-width` and `max-height` CSS properties to get the effect you want:

```
#container img {
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px:
}
```

Be aware that this does not work in IE6. To make it work there you may need to either scale the image serverside OR use expressions which are nasty. There are other workarounds which you can find on google :)

Comment: Good workaround. What happens in IE6, it just renders it at normal width and height?

Comment: IE6 will just ignore css properties it doesnt understand. Did you manage to find an acceptable workaround?

Comment: +1 This solution preserves the aspect ratio even of the y-axis or the x-axis is greater than 500px.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get much better results if you resize the images on the server. Resizing in the browser means the client is downloading much larger files than necessary, and the resizing quality is not great.

Comment: i agree with you to reduce size of download however, browsers are getting better and better at scaling nicely.

Comment: I am getting these images by calling a service which vends the url of the image, so I cant do much about resizing on server.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not fully doable with htm and css.

```
img{ width: 100% }
```

will make 1000x400 image to appear as 500x200 bu 400x1000 will appear as 500x1200.

You can use javascrpt like:

```
function scaleimage(id)
{
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if(image.offsetWidth > image.offsetHeight)
    {
         if(image.offsetWidth > 500)
         {
             image.offsetHeight = image.offsetHeight * 500 / image.offsetWidth;
             image.offsetWidth = 500;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         if(image.offsetHeight > 500)
         {
             image.offsetWidth = image.offsetWidth * 500 / image.offsetHeiht;
             image.offsetHeight = 500;
          }
    }
}
```

Sorry for poor formating, seems like my iPhone doesn't support it.

Comment: will give it a shot.. right now i'm rolling with max-width and max-height.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it on the server. Or manually before uploading them (if it's possible).

Answer (score -1):

You can use width and height CSS properties to get the effect you want:

## container img {

```
width:500px;
height:500px:
```

}

Be aware that this work in all browsers.

Thanks
Ptiwari.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt solve the problem.. i want the image to scale only on the longest dimension.. And just as a tip if you do this, images are going to look ugly as we are changing the aspect ratio of them.